# JPA Query for PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I have the below query which works when running through Postgres-

```
select * from my_schema.my_table where (jsonb_1 @> '"789"' or jsonb_2 @> '"789"') and (status != 'BAD_STATUS');
```

It checks if there's a value of `"789"` in `jsonb_1` (list of strings) example: `["456", "789"]` or `"789"` in `jsonb_2` (list of strings) example: `["123", "456"]` and with status not `BAD_STATUS`. I'm trying to represent the same query in Spring Data JPA (version 1.5.6.RELEASE) and tried the below two but getting exceptions.

Query1:

```
@Query(value = "select * from my_schema.my_table where (jsonb_1 @> :jsonbValue or jsonb_2 @> :jsonbValue) and (status != :badStatus)", nativeQuery = true)
List<MyEntity> findAllByJsonbValueAndStatusNot(@Param("jsonbValue") String jsonbValue, @Param("badStatus") String badStatus);
```

Exception:

```
2018-10-12 07:41:18,750 DEBUG http-nio-9030-exec-1 - [correlationId:, errorCode:] - org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions.122 - could not extract ResultSet [n/a]
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb @> character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 60
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:168)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:116)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2117)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)[...]
```

Query2:

```
@Query(value = "select * from my_schema.my_table where (jsonb_1 @> ?1 or jsonb_2 @> ?1) and (status != ?2)", nativeQuery = true)
List<MyEntity> findAllByJsonbValueAndStatusNot(String jsonbValue, String badStatus);
```

Exception:

```
2018-10-12 07:29:41,126 ERROR http-nio-9030-exec-1 - [correlationId:, errorCode:] - com.my.services.common.exception.ExceptionHandler.handleAppErrors.39 - Internal server error occurred
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! On JDKs < 8, you need to use @Param for named parameters, on JDK 8 or better, be sure to compile with -parameters.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! On JDKs < 8, you need to use @Param for named parameters, on JDK 8 or better, be sure to compile with -parameters.
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! On JDKs < 8, you need to use @Param for named parameters, on JDK 8 or better, be sure to compile with -parameters.
at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:181)
at [...]`
```

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace and the SQL statements that actually get executed. And the version of Spring Data JPA you are using.

Comment: @JensSchauder, done

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a typecasting issue. Try this

```
@Query(value = "select * from my_schema.my_table where (jsonb_1 @> :jsonbValue\:\:jsonb or jsonb_2 @> :jsonbValue\:\:jsonb) and (status != :badStatus)", nativeQuery = true)
```

or the alternative syntax

```
@Query(value = "select * from my_schema.my_table where (jsonb_1 @> cast(:jsonbValue as jsonb) or jsonb_2 @> cast(:jsonbValue as jsonb)) and (status != :badStatus)", nativeQuery = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's saying you can't use the operator `@>` to compare a string and a jsonb (which must be one of your column types in the DB). You'll have to cast the string as jsonb or the jsonb to string to do the comparison.

[Postgres Docs on Type Casts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS)

You can use the `LIKE` operator to compare strings on the cast string:

```
WHERE jsonb::varchar LIKE 'jsonbValue'
```

[LIKE operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html)

or use the @> operator on cast jsonb:

```
WHERE jsonb @> :jsonbValue::jsonb
```

[JSONb functions in postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

EDIT:

For the second query, you are using named parameters that don't exist in your named query. Either replace `?1` with `:jsonbValue` or remove the `@Param` annotations.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the postgres query. I'm having issues representing the same query in JPA, the query works fine while executing directly on the table.

Comment: my bad the second query never had the @Param annotations, copy paste error. :)