# How do I make PSQL think "keyword" is a variable when it is sent from Java Repository

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc

```
package com.rev.booktags_sts.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.rev.booktags_sts.model.Booktags;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface BooktagsRepository extends JpaRepository<Booktags, Long>{


    //Custom query
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM booktags s where s.tagname like '%keyword%';", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Booktags> findByKeyword(@Param("keyword") String keyword);
}
```

As you can see the word "keyword" is between the %s the problem is when a SELECT * is done PSQL thinks that I am asking for the word "keyword" so how do I turn the word "keyword" in the java environment into a variable so PSQL thinks it is whatever I put into the keyword variable

Comment: @par building a string is **the wrong approach for SQL as it causes the most important kind of security vulnerability in history, do not recommend that** even if it could work here, which it could not. It cannot work here because the string given to the decorator needs to exist at compile time, but the parameter needs to be evaluated at runtime based on what is passed to the function.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel interested to see the answer then, thanks

Comment: OP: The way you solve this problem is to a) know the terminology for what you are trying to do, and then b) [attempt a bit of research](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java+postgresql+%40query+parameterized), as is [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/). I was easily able to find you a [related existing Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771628/jpa-query-for-postgresql) and a [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query).

Comment: With a more specific search, I can find [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).

Answer (score 2):

The `@Query` decorator expects different syntax for parameterized queries. Following the example from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query.advanced-like) for interpolating an SQL `LIKE` parameter from the method parameters, try:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM booktags s WHERE s.tagname LIKE %?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Booktags> findByKeyword(String keyword);
```

Or, if you want to use [named parameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters), the parameter marker is instead `:`:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM booktags s WHERE s.tagname LIKE %:keyword", nativeQuery = true)
List<Booktags> findByKeyword(@Param("keyword") String keyword);
```